# Joomla! sub-page menu item indent

Tags: joomla, menu, joomla1.5

I am trying to indent 3rd level menu items on sub-pages in a Joomla! 1.5 install.  Can anyone throw me any tips for making this possible?

If you look on this page, you'll see that the page you're on, in the left menu, is vertically inline with all the other page links in the menu.  Since this is a sub-page of Hanson History, I would like Hanson Team to be indented a few pixels, so the user see's it's a sub-page of that menu item.

http://hanson.betabing.com/about-us/hanson-history/hanson-team

Thanks for looking,
Bill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS to target the second level unordered list

```
#content-left-interior ul.menu li ul li a span { padding-left:10px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

add this in template.css under templates/hanson/css

```
#content-left-interior li li {
   padding-left: 46px;
}
```